# Get two return values in JAVA

Tags: java, bluej

I have the following below code. I need to return month and year values from "getInput" method. Getting error as unreachable statement. I am using BlueJ IDE. How to get tow return values now. Please help.

```
public class CalendarTester
{

    public static void main(String[] args) { //method call for testing valid inputs from the user
       nputValidate();
    }

    public static void InputValidate(){ //Method to call functions for validation of inputs
        String UserInput="";
        UserInput=getInput();
        ValidateInput(UserInput);
    }

    public static String getInput(){ // To read user input
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the year (eg - 2016):");
        String year = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter the month (eg - 10):");
        String month = scanner.next();
        return year;
        return month;
    }

    public static boolean ValidateInput(String toValidation){ // Method to validate inputs
        boolean Pass=false;
        String finalString=toValidation.replaceAll("\\s+","");
        String matchingString="[0-9]{4,6}";
        if(finalString.matches(matchingString)){
            String Month=finalString.substring(0, 3);
            String Year = finalString.substring(0, 4);
            int month=Integer.parseInt(Month);
            int year=Integer.parseInt(Year);
            if(month>0 && month<=12){
                if(year>999 & year<=10000){
                    Pass=true;
                    Calendar calender = new Calendar();
                    boolean isLeapYear=calender.isLeapYear((short) year);
                    if(isLeapYear){
                        System.out.println("The given year " +year+ " is a leap Year");
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("The given year " +year+ " is not a leap Year");
                    }
                    byte TotalDaysInMonth=calender.TotalDaysOfMonth((byte) month,(short) year);
                    System.out.println("Total days in the month " +month+ "are "+TotalDaysInMonth);
                    byte week=calender.firstDayOfYear((short) year);
                    String FirstDayOfWeek ="";
                    switch (week) { //Case for first day of the week
                    case 0:
                        FirstDayOfWeek="Mon";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        FirstDayOfWeek="Tue";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        FirstDayOfWeek="Wed";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        FirstDayOfWeek="Thur";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        FirstDayOfWeek="Fri";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        FirstDayOfWeek="Sat";
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        FirstDayOfWeek="Sun";
                        break;
                    default:
                        FirstDayOfWeek="Invalid week input";
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.println("The first day of the year"+year+"is "+FirstDayOfWeek);
                    byte firstmonthday = calender.firstDayOfMonth((byte) month,(short) year);
                    String dayName = "";
                    switch(firstmonthday)//to print the first day of the month
                    {
                        case 0: dayName = "Sat"; break;
                        case 1: dayName = "Sun"; break;
                        case 2: dayName = "Mon"; break;
                        case 3: dayName = "Tue"; break;
                        case 4: dayName = "Wed"; break;
                        case 5: dayName = "Thur"; break;
                        default: dayName = "Fri"; break;
                    }
                    System.out.println("The first day of the month" +month+ "is " + dayName);
                    calender.printMonth((byte) month,(short) year);
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Invalid year input");
                    Pass=false;
                    InputValidate();
                }
            }
            else if(month<=0 || month>12){ //validates the month entered
                System.out.println("Invalid month input");
                Pass=false;
                InputValidate();
            }
        }
        return Pass;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a`java.time.YearMonth` class that you might want to use if you are using Java 8.

Comment: A more proper way would be to use two different functions: One for month, called `getMonth()` and one for year, called `getYear()`. Will give each function a well defined task. This does not apply if you have a certain connection to the classes though. In that case you may want a class, so that you can move all work of handling month and year to this class. Apart from this, it would be completely possible (and proper) to handle invariants directly in the getters. This will get rid of the `ValidateInput()` method.

Comment: Apart from this, I would also advice you to start learning a more commonly used IDE if you plan to continue with Java as a job. The currently most used IDEs are Intellij IDEA, Eclipse, Netbeans I think. Choose one of these since they are the ones that will be used in your company.

Answer (score 5):

The Java-idiomatic way of doing this is to make a new class containing the things that you want to return as members:

```
public static class Foo
{
    String year;
    String month;
}
```

and `return` an *instance* of that.

You'll find this is the approach that *scales* best. Eventually you'll end up adding all sorts of other functionality to this `class`.

You might even notice that it's too similar to some of the standard classes (`java.util.Date` and the newer `java.time.LocalDate`), and ditch the whole thing altogether.

Comment: It seems we now also have `java.time.YearMonth`.

Answer (score 0):

return **1 array** containing the **2 values**

Comment: Maybe not an array, though. Maybe a `java.time.LocalDate` (where you ignore the day field).

Comment: Or even a `java.time.YearMonth`..

Comment: Yes, that coulde resolve this particular case. but generaly, I think, if you want to return 2 or more Objects, of independent values, you can always use an `array` containing them. (if the Objects are of different type too) then will use an `ArrayList` instead

Answer (score 0):

Try using Array, you can assign 2 or more values :

```
public static String[] getInput(){ // To read user input
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter the year (eg - 2016):");
String year = scanner.next();
System.out.println("Please enter the month (eg - 10):");
String month = scanner.next();

return new String[]{year,month};
}
```